# Python Exceptions Handling : Exception don't work

Tags: python, error-handling, exception, try-catch

My code downloads files from an online file storage web service and unzip them. To run my script, I give it a date as argument (as mentioned here below). I want to add an error message if the date did not match any documents.

So assuming that I have one month of data (July), a valid date is an existing folder wich contains informations about the date in question (example : 07Jul2016). Obviously, a wrong date is an unexisting folder in my online file storage web service (example : 18Aug2016).

This is what I'm supposed to do in my main function :

```
download_usrm(date = sys.argv[1])
```

And obviously, this is my command line to run my script :

```
python Extractor.py 07Jul2016
```

This is the code in question (This is just the try/except part):

```
if key_element.startswith(date):

    try:                
        if not os.path.exists(working_directory+ '/' +date_file+ '/'+parentKey):
            os.makedirs(working_directory+ '/' +date_file+ '/'+parentKey)
        key.get_contents_to_filename(working_directory+ '/' +date_file+ '/'+keyString)

       for f in glob.glob(working_directory+ '/' + date_file+ '/'+ 'usrm' + '/'+ file_name+ '*.zip'):
           zip_ref = zipfile.ZipFile(f, 'a')
           zip_ref.extractall(working_directory + '/' + date_file+ '/'+ 'usrm' + '/' + file_id)
           zip_ref.close()
           os.remove(f)

    except Exception as e:
        print('ERROR MESSAGE : Your search did not match any documents. Try rynning with another date.', e)
```

So with a valid date, my code is normally running. With a wrong date, I have nothing. The error message is not displayed.

What might be wrong? Any help appreciated. Thx !

Comment: Which part do you expect to raise an exception here?

Comment: If the date is invalid, your `glob` for loop will simply not find any files and continue without raising an exception

Comment: @deceze : All this part. I want to have the error message if the date gived as argument is wrong. Must I maybe move my "try" before my condition "if key_element.startswith(date):" ?

Comment: No, what you must do is run some code which will actually **raise an exception**. None of the code you run raises any exception, so none can be caught. At the very least include some `assert (date is valid)` check somewhere.